# create polygon button in .net maui in .xaml

Tags: maui

I want to create a triangle button or pentagon button or Irregular polygon button in .NET MAUI that has button properties and events.

I read this document [Create a Polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/shapes/polygon?view=net-maui-8.0)
that describe how to create  polygon but I can not use it as a button.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Create a Custom Polygon Button-Shape in XAML**

   You will need to use a Grid or similar layout container, add your Path or shapes
   to create the polygon look, and then place a Label or similar for the text. You
   then add a tap gesture recognizer to handle taps.

```
<ContentView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPolygonButtonTapped"/>
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <Grid WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100">
        <Path Fill="LightBlue" Stroke="Purple" StrokeThickness="3" Aspect="Fill">
            <Path.Data>
                <!-- Adapt Points to Path Data as needed -->
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 10,100 L 100,100 L 55,0 Z"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Label Text="Test" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

2. **Add Tap Event Handler in Code-Behind**

   In your page's code-behind, you define the OnPolygonButtonTapped method to handle the tap event:

```
private void OnPolygonButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the tap event, such as navigation or command execution
    Console.WriteLine("Polygon button tapped!");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, you can implement custom renderer but I think it is more complicated than implementing just a shape handling the Tap Event in code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the click event is also fire around the triangle you have formed. Is there a way to call event only the click inside the triangle?

Comment: You are right, after testing it again it is also fired around the triangle. This is only what found that was useful. The alternative is to use custom renderer. I will search again and if I find something useful I will share it with you.

Comment: You are right. Maui Shape is a View while a View is Rectangle. Though you tap outside the triangle, still it is inside the Rectangle and will trigger the tap event.

Comment: You may get the x,y position and do some math caculation if the point you tapped is inside the Path. It might be easy for a triangle but much complicated for irregular polygon.